# Using tcpdump to monitor Chromecast activity

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

*Background: On my home setup, all traffic is routed through a single TP-link router which currently has OpenWRT intalled. I set up DNS ad blocking with a pixelserv setup, so all devices on my network automatically have a rudimentary ad-block. However my Chromecast still displays YouTube ads. I'm trying to find the hostname it connects to.*

I want to monitor the activity of a device on my network (a Chromecast). The most logical way to do this seems to run tcpdump on the router. I am not familiar enough with it, though, to succeed.

I used ifconfig to list my interfaces (I have wlan0 and wlan1). I tried commands like this:

```
tcpdump -vv -i wlan0 | grep Chromecast
```

expecting to see some traffic from the device to some remote site.

However, I'm not sure how to interpret the result and whether there even is useful information in it:

```
debian.lan.51469 > Chromecast.lan.8009: Flags [P.], cksum 0x0743 (correct), seq 3470496191:3470495026, ack 2613442937, win 1444, options [nop,nop,TS val 1863051 ecr 6696623], length 115
Chromecast.lan.8009 > debian.lan.51469: Flags [.], cksum 0xe938 (correct), seq 1, ack 115, win 411, options [nop,nop,TS val 6697122 ecr 1863050], length 0
Chromecast.lan.39457 > 74.125.8.26.https: Flags [.], cksum 0xee29 (correct), seq 1, ack 4294950448, win 214, length 0
74.125.8.26.https > Chromecast.lan.39457: Flags [.], cksum 0x7084 (correct), seq 5616:7020, ack 1, win 388, length 1404
```

So, I'm with these questions:

- Can I use tcpdump to find out the host the device connects to? How?
- How can you interpret the captured traffic in this case? Is there really anything useful in it?
- Is there any other/better monitoring tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few other monitoring tools listed here: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10073/difference-between-sniffer-tools

**Wireshark** is generally a good place to start if you want to look at some more detail, do filtering for specific traffic, etc.  e.g. [see screenshot here](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUseMainWindowSection.html)

For your situation, you could try sending the tcpdump output to another machine via SSH and view the data with Wireshark. Have a look here:
http://blog.nielshorn.net/2010/02/using-wireshark-with-remote-capturing/

Good luck!

Comment: When posting a link to another blog/website/youtube video, try to post a summary or list of key commands so that if the site goes offline or the content changes it is still a useful answer.

Comment: I capped all traffic during one of the commercials with `tcpdump -i wlan0 -w /tmp/capped.pcap -C 4 -W 10`. Stopped capping with ^C, copied and combined it with scp and mergecap. I am quite stuck at getting useful information from it with Wireshark, though. Will keep you posted! (Seeing your screenshot I seem to be missing 1 of 3 panels, only the bottom 2 appear. That might explain my confusion)

Comment: I found it! First of all, the Packet Llist in Wireshark had zero height. Secondly, I found DNS requests from the CCast to 8.8.8.8 - Google's own DNS server. That's why it wasn't poisoned and why the ads still worked. I guess I'll either try to intercept the 8.8.8.8 requests or use iptables to block the ads... Thanks for the answer, marked as solution.

Comment: Which, with 20/20 hindvision, is easy to find o/c https://adfreetime.com/get-started/chromecast/