# Reroute direct DNS requests on OpenWRT

Tags: router, dns, openwrt, adblock

On my router with OpenWRT, I use dnsmasq for DNS poisoning to block ads. If the host is on the list, the router replies to the DNS request with 192.168.99.99, which only and always serves a 1x1 transparent gif (the pixelserv method).

However, local devices can bypass this by directly using their own DNS server. **How can I reroute these DNS requests so the ads are blocked?**.

I tried commands like these (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 being the DNS servers, 192.168.1.102 the source device, 192.168.1.1 the IP of my router):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 8.8.8.8 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 8.8.4.4 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1

# or:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -s 192.168.1.102 -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-port 53
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -s 192.168.1.102 -p tcp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-post 53
```

I tried adding adding a traffic rule through the OpenWrt admin panel -> Source NAT, matching "Any TCP, UDP From IP 192.168.1.102 in lan To any host, port 53 in lan", with action "Rewrite to source IP 192.168.1.1, port 53". I believe this is effectuated in iptables as well either way.

But I find the DNS queries are still resolving:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# tcpdump -vvv -i wlan0 port 53

Chromecast.lan.42591 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: [udp sum ok] 57897+ A? pubads.g.doubleclick.net. (42)
google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > Chromecast.lan.42591: [udp sum ok] 57897 q: A? pubads.g.doubleclick.net. 5/0/0 pubads.g.doubleclick.net. [5h59m59s] CNAME partnerad.l.doubleclick.net., partnerad.l.doubleclick.net. [4m59s] A 74.125.136.157, partnerad.l.doubleclick.net. [4m59s] A 74.125.136.156, partnerad.l.doubleclick.net. [4m59s] A 74.125.136.155, partnerad.l.doubleclick.net. [4m59s] A 74.125.136.154 (132)
```

Maybe a completely different method, for example through dnsmasq, would work? I could not find this, however.

(I've found some explanation on how to reroute to another remote DNS server, but that won't help me here. It's mostly for [unblocking regions](https://nowhere.dk/articles/using-openwrt-to-change-chromecasts-dns-resolvers) or [for Tomato or DD-WRT](https://adfreetime.com/get-started/chromecast/). Also, this is closely related to my [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/937095/using-tcpdump-to-monitor-chromecast-activity))

Comment: try `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br-lan -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.1`

Comment: That actually works! Can you make it into an answer so you can elaborate and I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br-lan -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.1`

**Explanation**
iptables uses chains to route traffic. 
We use `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING` to select the chain which we want to add the new rule.  Then we narrow down the selection to include only traffic going out to the internet by selecting the interface `-i br-lan` which is OpenWRT's LAN interface. Since we're only redirecting `DNS udp 53`  we add `-p udp --dport 53`. Now that we only get DNS packets,  we redirect them to the local DNS server using `-j DNAT --to 192.168.1.1`. You can replace the destination with any DNS server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I especially wonder why I can capture the packets on wlan0 but need to use br-lan to reroute them... And probably would need to add the same filter for tcp as well (for the larger responses)?

Comment: @TacoV: wlan0 is a physical interface. It does not have an IP address. The IP address is bound to br-lan.

Comment: @tacov wlan0 is the wireless physical interface. So all you get is wifi traffic.